# Good way to display a series of images

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, user-interface, google-chrome

I'm embarking on creating a new app that requires to display a series of images that are consecutive.  Each follows on from the next.  Kind of like a comic book I guess, but not necessarily all contained within a larger grid.

Each image will be quite big, so I was thinking that I'd show thumbnails which will expand when the mouse is hovered over (or clicked?).

I would like to know of your opinions on the best way to display this on a web page, thats perhaps more easily viewed than a set of images seperated by arrows (i.e. IMAGE1.JPG --> IMAGE2.JPG --> IMAGE3.JPG).

Any abstract or out of the ordinary ideas are very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice comic book-like implementation http://www.20thingsilearned.com/

Take a look at jCarousel or the jQuery Tools Scrollable plugin http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html

Comment: Wow I do like the look of the Scrollable plugin

Answer (score 1):

If they are comfortable to view in a from-top-to-bottom ashion you could do what Bing's image search does: Simply load the next image as the viewport scrolls down. That way you don't have pagination which is something that at least I don't really like.

Of course, if only a single image or a few are of interest to the potential viewer, then a grid with thumbnails (if they provide enough information) would be the best way.

Side note: Don't necessarily rely on hover, since some devices are incapable of generating hover events. Think touch-only interfaces for example.